# Call a function from MasterPage which is located in different folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My website hierarchy looks like this-

[image]

What I want to do is to call a function which is in `Login.master.cs` file into `Default.aspx.cs`.

If the Default.aspx was in the same Login folder the master page would have been called by

```
var master = Master as Login_Master; 
master.myFunction();
```

but the above code doesn't work if the master page is in another folder.
How could I call the function?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `Default` using `Login_Master` as its master page?  In what way is this failing?  What's the error?

Comment: No. I am setting the master page to Default by Page. PreInit(). The error is its not getting the refrence of the class of Login.master.cs

Comment: You might need to reference the namespace in a using directive at the top of the file if Login_Master is in a different namespace than Default.  But if Login_Master isn’t that page’s master page then this isn’t going to work anyway.  The “as” operation will return null since it’s the wrong type.